# bacteria colony growing

Tags: calculus

Heres my problem,

A biologist determines that, t hours after a bacterial colony was established, the population of bacteria in the colony is changing at a rate given by
$P′(t)=2e^t/(1+e^t)$
million bacteria per hour, $0\le t\le7.$

If the bacterial colony started with a population of 1 million, how many bacteria are present in the colony after the 7-hour experiment? Round your answer to 2 decimal places.

I tried to solve the problem as 1000000+integration from 0 to 7 of the given equation but it didnt work. any advice or help?

Comment: What do you mean, it didn't work? If you show us the work you did leading to a wrong answer, maybe we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: If you can just tell us what wrong answer you got, someone might be able to guess what mistake you made. By the way, how do you know your answer is wrong?

Comment: The idea of $0.01$ bacterium is curious

Comment: By the way, if the population $P(t)$ is in ***millions*** of bacteria, then $P(0)=1,$ right? So don't you want $$1+\int_0^7\frac{2e^t}{1+e^t}dt?$$

Comment: @bof: though you might be expected to multiply the overall answer by $1$ million

Comment: @Henry Maybe not. I think "2 decimal places" means to the nearest $10^4$ bacteria, not to the nearest $10^{-2}$ bacteria, which seems overly precise. Of course the units need to be expressed.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution**
$$P(t)=P(t_0)+P'(t_0)(t-t_0)+R_2(x)$$
where
$$R_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x}f''(t)(x-t)^2dt$$
**Second solution**
$$\int \frac{2e^t}{1+e^t}dt=2\ln(1+e^t)+c$$
in the other words
$$P(7)=P(0)+2\ln(1+e^7)-2\ln(1+e^0)$$